# How to add 'api' on the devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The routes of devise **routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
```

makes the routes like this:

```
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
```

How can i make it like

```
      new_user_session GET    /api/users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /api/users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /api/users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /api/users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /api/users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /api/users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by:

```
    scope path: :api do
      devise_for :users
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
namespace :api do
  devise_for :users
end
```

Comment: No, then it's `new_user_session GET    /api/users/sign_in(.:format)       api/sessions#new`